# Difference between jquery form validation and model validation in cakephp?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cakephp

if you are going to validate cakephp form using ajax, so not to reload the page, do you have to define validation array in the model? thank you.

Comment: server-side validation vs client-side validation . Recommend to use both

Comment: client side validation is optional; server side validation is not. Unless you like having crap in your db, and people hacking your sites =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always want to validate everything because [you should ***never*** trust any input](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/phpblog/entry/thou_shalt_never_trust_user?lang=en). This is a golden rule no matter what kind of program you write. Website or sensor. I would not even trust the input from a sensor for example and validate the data coming from it. Besides the server side validation you also should use the [Security Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) of CakePHP to secure your forms and site against attacks. You might want to use google to lookup a few attacks that the Security Component prevents, check the manual for a list.

Javascript runs only in your browser. You could simply disable javascript and enter whatever you want. Further you can edit the markup and add an additional input there and submit that changed form. Now make your guess what happens when you add a hidden field "role" and give the value "admin" for example...